# java coding for motorola RFid reader model FX7400 on mac/linux

Tags: java, macos, dll, rfid, motorola

I am trying to code for a motorola RFID reader using java and a mac os.

The error is:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no RFIDAPI3_JNI_HOST in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at com.mot.rfid.api3.API3Natives.<clinit>(API3Natives.java:2087)
    at com.mot.rfid.api3.RFIDReader.connect(RFIDReader.java:371)
    at EventHandler.connectToReader(EventHandler.java:94)
    at main.main(main.java:11)`
```

searching for the solution, looks like I need a RFIDAPI3_JNI_HOST.dll, I have this file I don't know if there is a way to use it on mac/linux systems.

Is there a way to code/debug/run for this RFID reader using mac ?
Is the solution find a way to use this .dll on java path on mac ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have developed two desk app using .Net, I've never seen any documentation related to Java for this reader (neither any from Motorola). Have you taken a look the release notes? If so, you might have to hard code it.

Comment: How are you connecting the device to your MAC

Comment: I am connecting using network IP

Comment: hi.. @igor.. can u plz send me that RFIDAPI3_JNI_HOST.dll file..

Comment: @Igor... i think we cannot find this file in internet. so can u plz share me

Comment: Sorry for the delay. it is hehe https://www.dropbox.com/s/0iq6unmpg9pqqpe/RFIDAPI3_JNI_HOST.dll?dl=0 if it is useful please click on the up arrow . Thanks

Comment: We usually install a motorola SDK EMDK-Java-RFID-x86-010002.msi from their website that helps in solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

You cant use this on MAC.  This library is JNI layer provider and works only on Windows OS.

I dont think there is library for OSX.

May be you can search for LLRP libs for Mac or linux, since reader is LLRP compatible, it should work.